# How do I go back to a certain line for a checkpoint in my RPG game?

Tags: java

I need help making a checkpoint in my text RPG game. I give the user 2 choices and one of them gets them killed. After they die, I want them to go back to the start of the checkpoint, but I don't know what to do.

I've tried while (true) {, continue;, break;, and it's just messing up my code. The section I post is pretty messy but I hope you can see what I'm trying to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {
    public static void main (String []args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
           System.out.println("These men are on the other side of the street. They're carrying large laser rifles, and pointing them at civilians.");
           try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
           System.out.println("You quickly find cover behind a large tree near the Square, and they haven't seen you yet.");
           try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
           System.out.println("Do you choose to shoot as many as you can, or find a way to save the civilians? (Hint: shoot them or save people)");
           String input2 = sc.nextLine();

           switch(input2) {
           case "shoot them": 
               System.out.println("You decide to try to shoot as many as you can. You take down 2, but the 5 men remaining have taken cover. They now know exactly where you are now. They toss a grenade your way.");
           try {
               Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
           System.out.println("*BOOM*");
           try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
           System.out.println("You died by explosion.");
           try {
               Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
           System.out.println("GAME OVER");
          continue;
           case "save people":
               System.out.println("Good decision..."); 
               break;



           }
        }
    }
}
```

If the user writes "shoot them", the result is that they die, but the code doesn't go back to the Checkpoint.

Comment: `System.exit(0);
      continue;
` - what do you think will happen here?

Comment: yeah i got rid of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `System.exit(0);` line.

If that line is removed, the `while` loop starts again because the `continue` is executed, and the checkpoints messages will be displayed.

Comment: @Andreas why not? If the line is removed, the `while` starts again because the `continue` is executed.

Comment: @Andreas I've added more details, but the solutions is the same.

Comment: What if OP wants to have a checkpoint that **isn't at the start** of the game? Sure, continue will reset it, but it will remove ALL of the progress the player has made. @Villat

Comment: So I removed the System.exit(0); line, and it does go back to the checkpoint. But the problem is, when I chose the other option (save people), it still loops to the checkpoint at the start even when I don't want it to.

Comment: @Elliot you can add a `break;` after the message `System.out.println("Good decision...);`

Comment: I thought that's what I did already. (EDIT): adding a break after s.o.pln("Good decision..); just loops back to the "checkpoint"

Comment: @Elliot could you update the code in your post to see what do you currently have?

Comment: @Elliot you need another `break;`. The first one is breaking the `switch` case, and you need a new one to break the `while`

Comment: I didn't know that. I did it and it works as I wanted it to! Thx sm @Villat

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't CodeReview but FYI, you can add `throws InterruptedException` to your main method signature so that you don't have to catch all of those exceptions.

One basic way that you might implement an RPG game is using an object graph, that is, you have a class `Option` and `Scenario` and traverse it to play out the RPG. For example:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scenario root = new Scenario("Welcome to the forest", 500);
        Scenario left = new Scenario("You went left!", 500);
        Scenario right = new Scenario("You went right!", 500);

        Option step1a = new Option("Go left", left);
        Option step1b = new Option("Go right", right);
        Option step1c = new Option("Go back to the beginning", root);

        root.branches.add(step1a);
        root.branches.add(step1b);
        root.branches.add(step1c);

        Scenario current = root;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(current.text);

            if (current.branches.size() == 0) break;

            Thread.sleep(current.delay);
            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            for (int i = 0; i < current.branches.size(); i++) {
                System.out.printf("%s. %s\n", i, current.branches.get(i).text);
            }
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            current = current.branches.get(choice).result;
        }

        System.out.println("Game over!");
    }
}

class Scenario {

    List<Option> branches = new ArrayList<>();
    String text;
    int delay;

    public Scenario(String text, int delay) {
        this.text = text;
        this.delay = delay;
    }

}

class Option {

    Scenario result;
    String text;

    public Option(String text, Scenario result) {
        this.text = text;
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.